# FUSE fseek unexpected behaviour with direct_io

Tags: fuse, fseek

I'm trying to write a FUSE filesystem that presents streamable music as mp3 files. I don't want to start to stream the audio when just the ID3v1.1 tag is read, so I mount the filesystem with direct_io and max_readahead=0.

But when I do this (which is also what libid3tag does), I get reads of 2752 bytes with offset -2880 bytes from the end:

```
char tmp[255];
FILE* f = fopen("foo.mp3", "r");
fseek(f, -128, SEEK_END);
fread(tmp, 1, 10, f);
```

Why is this? I expect to get a call to read with an offset exactly 128 bytes from the end with size 10..

The amount of bytes read seems to vary somewhat.

Comment: Replacing fread with read makes no difference.

Comment: My temporary solution is to add 8192 bytes of padding at the end, before the ID3v1.1 tag. Not pretty, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue and filed an issue with s3fs. Checkout issue : http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=241

additionally, checkout line 1611 in the s3fs.cpp:

http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/source/browse/trunk/src/s3fs.cpp?r=316

```
 // error check this

 // fseek (pSourceFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
```